# How to fix class not found error in firebase jvm?

Tags: java

In this code, class not found error shows. how to solve this?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    com/google/api/client/googleapis/util/Utils
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.<init> 
    (FirebaseOptions.java:233)
    at aaaa.app.main(app.java:25)
Caused by: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.util.Utils
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 2 more
```

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


public class Fireb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileInputStream serviceAccount;
        FirebaseOptions options = null;
        try {
            serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("C:\\firebase-adminsdk-4po4a-5ce6c60b81.json");
            options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("..................")
                    .build();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        String topics = getDatafromFirebase();
        System.out.println(topics);
        System.out.println("Everything right!");
    }

    private static String getDatafromFirebase() {
        CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference();

        dbRef.child("topics").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    for(DataSnapshot s:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Topics t = s.getValue(Topics.class);
                        b.append(t.getName());
                        b.append(" ");
                    }
                    done.countDown();
                }
                else {
                    b.append("No existe ");
                    done.countDown();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                b.append("Error: "+error.getDetails());
                done.countDown();
            }
            });
        try {
            done.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is usually easier to read error messages if you put them in a code block.

Comment: Are you sure you have all the dependencies and they are all up to date? Can you include your Maven or Gradle file, if you are using one of them (which you should be). If you are not using Maven or Gradle, how are you getting the Firebase JARs, and how are you putting them on the classpath?

Comment: I'm not using maven/gradle. I just downloaded libraries, and add them to the build path as referred libraries. @MosheKatz